# Wrong result after PHP to Python 3.5 translation

Tags: php, python, code-translation

I've written an implementation of the selection- and insertion-sortingalgorithms in PHP and wanted to translate them to Python as a test to compare the runtime.

As I'm relatively new to Python I'm wondering why this code doesn't work properly. It returns the array given in the function call.

Python Script:

```
def insertionSort(sort_array: list):
    for i in range(0, len(sort_array)-1, +1):
        for j in range (i+1, 0, -1):
            if sort_array[j-1] > sort_array[j]:
                temp = sort_array[j-1]
                sort_array[j-1] = sort_array[j]
                sort_array[j] = temp
    return sort_array

print(insertionSort([11, 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 9]))
```

> [11, 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 9]
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

PHP Script (working)

```
function insertionSort($sort_array){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sort_array); $i++){                         
      for ($j = $i + 1; $j > 0; $j--){                          
        if($sort_array[$j-1] > $sort_array[$j]){
          $temp = $sort_array[$j-1];
          $sort_array[$j-1] = $sort_array[$j];
          $sort_array[$j] = $temp;               
        }          
      } 
    }
    return $sort_array;
}
```

Thank you in advance. Any critic of my Python style is welcome.

---

**Edit**: Apparently it's a problem with my local system, as an online interpreter returns the correctly sorted array: https://repl.it/GULW

Comment: @linusg Quote:"It returns the array given in the function call." It basically doesn't sort the array. I guess the problem is caused by either the range and/or the de/incrementing

Comment: @linusg well..it seems to work on every online ide, see edit. But everything is correct or can I simplify anything?

Comment: @linusg Fedora 24 with PyCharm using 3.5. Problem is PyCharm, call via console works. @ Downvoter: Wow, why the downvote?

Comment: Np, was just curious why ppl on SO downvote w/o a comment. But yeah, seems to be an IDE specific problem

Comment: @linusg Strange, rebooted ans same problem. Guess I have to check all configs